# Importe large csv (>2Go) file into access 2010/2013

Tags: ms-access, csv, import, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to import a large file (>2Go) into Microsoft Access 2010/2013 but I really can't even start the process of importation.

When I choose the file and I validate, I get this error message:
[image]

The message is in Frensh, and it means; the file doesn't contain any data or the file is very large.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The maximum allowed size for an Access database file is [2 gigabytes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854).  You need a database whose capacity is larger than Access or a smaller CSV file.

Comment: @HansUp Is it possible to split the original CSV file into 2 files and apply an UNION Query ?

Comment: Perhaps you could create 2 Access database files, each containing half of the original CSV data.  However 1 byte from the CSV does not necessarily translate to only 1 byte in the db file.  But if you can do it, you can theoretically `UNION` the two tables.  Unfortunately, if that working data set exceeds 2 GB, Access may want to use a temporary file to hold it ... and the temporary file size is also limited to a maximum of 2 GB.  Even if you can somehow avoid the file size restriction, such a query would likely be painfully slow.  Gord's suggestion is the only practical solution IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper limit on the size of a Microsoft Access database file is 2GB. Since a table must reside within a single file the upper limit on the size of an Access table is 2GB (less the overhead of the database file itself).

While you *might* be able to split the CSV file and import it into 2 separate tables (in 2 separate .accdb files), it would definitely be inconvenient and probably would be slow. You should consider storing your data in SQL Server Express, where the upper limit on the size of a database is 10GB.

Comment: Because the user can only manipulate Data in an Access Database!!